# Spring boot: JPA incorrectly adds where clause

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have three entity classes; `Student`, `Subject` and `StudentSubject`.

`Student` has one to many relation on `StudentSubject`, and `Subject` also has one to many relation on `StudentSubject`.

Student class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<StudentSubject> subjects;
    //more elements
}
```

Subject class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Teacher teacher;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<StudentSubject> students;
    //more elements
}
```

StudentSubject class

```
@Entity
@IdClass(StudentSubjectId.class)
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentSubject implements Serializable {

    //Primary keys
    @Id
    @Column(name = "subject_id")
    Long subjectId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_email")
    String studentEmail;

    String uid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Subject subject;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Student student;
}
```

I have 3 classes, and not 2, because there are attributes specific to each student subject pair. Hence this arrangement.

When I read a subject from repository, as such

```
Subject subject = subjectRepository.findByNameAndTeacher(subjectName, teacher);
subject.getStudents();
```

all it's details are correct, except for list of students. It is always empty.(checked this by adding breakpoint)

---

The queries that are executed by Hibernate/JPA are,

To get subject(?)

```
select
    subject0_.id as id1_3_,
    subject0_.name as name2_3_,
    subject0_.teacher_email as teacher_3_3_ 
from
    subject subject0_ 
    left outer join
        teacher teacher1_ 
        on subject0_.teacher_email = teacher1_.email 
where
    subject0_.name =? 
    and teacher1_.email =?
```

To select student list(?)

```
select
    students0_.student_email as student_1_2_0_,
    students0_.subject_id as subject_2_2_0_,
    students0_.student_email as student_1_2_1_,
    students0_.subject_id as subject_2_2_1_,
    students0_.uid as uid3_2_1_,
    subject1_.id as id1_3_2_,
    subject1_.name as name2_3_2_,
    subject1_.teacher_email as teacher_3_3_2_,
    teacher2_.email as email1_5_3_,
    teacher2_.name as name2_5_3_ 
from
    student_subject students0_ 
    left outer join
        subject subject1_ 
        on students0_.subject_id = subject1_.id 
    left outer join
        teacher teacher2_ 
        on subject1_.teacher_email = teacher2_.email 
where
    students0_.student_email =?
```

and some more.

I think the issue here is that the last where clause is incorrectly added, and common attributes in tables are not shown once. How do I fix this?

Comment: you have not specified fetch type. set it to Eager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping has a typo. In `Subject` class, it should be     `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subject")` instead of `mappedBy="student"` hence your wrong where clause.

This is the reason it is using 
`where students0_.student_email =?`
instead of
`where students0_.subject_id =?` as it thinks the way to get to students from subject is through `student_email` column as indicated by your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified fetch type. This should fix it.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<StudentSubject> students;
```

Comment: Is that all? I added fetchtype in subject class for students as you mentioned, but hibernate still uses the where clause.

Comment: does it fetch students after adding fetch attribute?

Comment: No it doesn't. But without where clause it does work when I tried the query directly on db.